# Validate bearer JWT

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I'm quite new to Web API and i still don't get it how to request n JWT.
In My **Startup.cs** i configured OAuth and my custom JWT:

**CustomJwtFormat.cs**

```
public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    private readonly string issuer = string.Empty;
    private readonly int timeoutMinutes = 60;

    public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
    {
        this.issuer = issuer;
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        string audience = "all";
        var secret = Convert.FromBase64String("mySecret");
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var expires = now.AddMinutes(timeoutMinutes);
        string signatureAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256";
        string digestAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

        var signingKey = new SigningCredentials(
                new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(secret), signatureAlgorithm, digestAlgorithm);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, data.Identity.Claims,
                                         now, expires, signingKey);

        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return tokenString;
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I managed retrieving a token with Postman.
[image: Postman Token Request]

Now my next problem: as long as i send a valid jwt everything works ok. But whenn i send e.g. 'bearer 12345' i get the error message

> IDX10708: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string: '12345'.

...in Visual Studio. Where do i need to put in the token validation? Make a new class and put the TokenSecurityHandler anywhere?